# Page not found (404) Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/login1

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-templates

when I log in to my 'login' page, the browser shows this error:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/login1

Using the URLconf defined in webapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. admin/
2. Home/ [name='Home']
3. login/ [name='login']
4. Signup/ [name='Signup']
5. login1/ [name='login1']

The current path, login/login1, didn't match any of these.

here's login.html file:

```
<body>
    <center> <h1> Student Login Form </h1> </center>
    <form method="post" action='login1'>       
        {% csrf_token %}       
        <h1 style="color:red"> {{ error}} </h1>        
        <div class="container">            
            <label>Username : </label>            
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>            
            <label>Password : </label>            
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>            
            <button type="submit">Login</button>            
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me            
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn"> Cancel</button>            
            <a href="{% url 'Signup' %}"> SignUp </a>       
        </div>    
    </form>
</body>
```

here's urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from application import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Home/', views.Home , name = "Home"),
    path('login/', views.login,name = 'login'),
    path('Signup/', views.Signup , name = 'Signup'),
    path('login1/',views.login1,name='login1'),
]
```

here's views.py:

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def login1(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        uname = request.POST['username']
        pwd = request.POST['pass']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=uname, password=pwd)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'Home.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': 'invalid credential details'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'Signup.html')
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably in this line:

```
<form method="post" action='login1'>
```

Better to write the value of `action` attribute this way.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login1' %}">
```